# How can I Loop through Array Items and Change Value every time Button is clicked

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

How can I run through array items and Loop through every single time whenever I clicked the button and change the value based on the array Items that is inside the array.

```
<img src="/assets/a-puppy-1642002.jpg" alt="Random Pictures" id="images">
<div>
     <button id="img-changer">Random</button>
</div>   


document.getElementById('img-changer').addEventListener('click', (btn) =>{
    let src = "src";
    let srcpath = "/assets/"
    let imgstock = [
        'Birds in Flowers Romantic Seamless Pattern Vector Background.jpg',
        'bucegi-mountains-1641852.jpg',
        'cat-and-kittens-1641561.jpg',
        'happy-doggy-1642001.jpg',
        'landscape-waterfall-1641818.jpg',
        'new-dawn-1641926.jpg',
        'river-of-the-world-1642010.jpg',
        'annie-at-home-1641997.jpg',
        'a-puppy-1642002.jpg'
    ]   
    
    document.getElementById('images').setAttribute(src, `${srcpath}${imgstock}`);
})
```

I'd like to run it indefinitely, like when is in the end of the Array item it will back to imgstock[0] then run again.

I've tried forEach and Map method

```
imgstock.forEach(img => {
        for(i = 0; i < img.toString(); i++){
            let newImg = img[i];
        }
    })
```

It returns undefined.
If my question seems so dumb, I apologize.

And if there's anything that can shorten or methods that can reduce my code. Please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear in your question. On Click of the button, do you want all the images to loop through one after the other, or you want to go to the next image & then on second click go to next?

Comment: @ShivangamSoni I want it to go to next image, then if theres no image left it will start again on top of the array of images

Comment: I have added my answer. Look at it if that's what you needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest Solution for this would be having a `active counter variable` which changes on every click, keeping tack of which image is being displayed.

```js
// Active Image Index Holder
let activeImage = 0;

document.getElementById('img-changer').addEventListener('click', (btn) => {
  let src = "src";
  let srcpath = "/assets/"
  let imgstock = [
    'Birds in Flowers Romantic Seamless Pattern Vector Background.jpg',
    'bucegi-mountains-1641852.jpg',
    'cat-and-kittens-1641561.jpg',
    'happy-doggy-1642001.jpg',
    'landscape-waterfall-1641818.jpg',
    'new-dawn-1641926.jpg',
    'river-of-the-world-1642010.jpg',
    'annie-at-home-1641997.jpg',
    'a-puppy-1642002.jpg'
  ]

  // Incrementing the Active Image Index If it Overflows, then Resetting to 0
  activeImage = activeImage + 1 < imgstock.length ? activeImage + 1 : 0;

  document.getElementById('images').setAttribute(src, `${srcpath}${imgstock[activeImage]}`);
})
```

```html
<img src="/assets/a-puppy-1642002.jpg" alt="Random Pictures" id="images">
<div>
  <button id="img-changer">Random</button>
</div>
```